# How to detect when user turns on/off talkback in android programmatically

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to update the UI based on accessibility option (i.e. talkback on/off). When user turns on talkback, i need to show some helper text else the helper text should be hidden.

As we also have shortcuts (In Pixel device, long pressing on both up and down volume keys) to enable/disable talkback. Is there any way to detect whether talkback is enabled/disabled, when i am on XYZ activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AccessibilityManager.AccessibilityStateChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.AccessibilityStateChangeListener) to receive whether listen to changes in Accessibilty Service.

Unfortunately this will be true if **ANY** of the accessibility services are enabled.

```
AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager= (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);

// Put this in onCreate
accessibilityManager.addAccessibilityStateChangeListener(new AccessibilityManager.AccessibilityStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityStateChanged(boolean b) {
        accessibilityChanged(b);
    }
});
accessibiltyChanged(accessibiltyManager.isEnabled());

void accessibiltyChanged (Boolean enabled) {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

You can also try using [getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager#getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(int)). This will return the list of all active accessibility services. But this will not be a **listener** meaning you'll not get a callback if this changes. A hack would be to call this function at regular intervals to check if anything has changed.

Comment: Thank you, but calling this function in regular interval will be costly operation. How to call AccessibilityManager.AccessibilityStateChangeListener this listener?

Comment: Thank you, Code provided above helped. Also, can you please elaborate "Unfortunately this will be true if ANY of the accessibility services are enabled" this statement. I did not get what exactly it means.

Comment: This callback will be fired if any of the accessibilty services are enabled (like switch access or TTS or select to speak). So let's suppose you enabled talkback. This callback would be fired. Now you enabled TTS and disable talback. In that case you would expect it to fire with value false. But it will not as one of the accessibilty service is enabled. To sum it up, when the first accessibilty service is enabled this fires with true and when the last accessibilty service is disabled it fires with false.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. So, we can use both provided methods to make it work i feel. If we call **getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList()**method inside **onAccessibilityStateChanged()** method to check whether Talkback is enabled or not right. But i did not find exact type to match from the list. Can you please let me know, how to compare for talkback type.